# How to import excel/CSV data into MongoDB collection/documents in a programmatic way(MERN)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, csv, mongoimport

I have an excel sheet with employee data. My task is to store the data from excel file in MongoDB database > employee collection(a row from excel sheet in mongodb document). I'm doing all this in a react application. I thought of using mongoimport. Since I need it in a CSV or Json format, I converted my excel file to CSV using SheetJs npm package and created a blob file of type csv. And then using the below command I was able to import that CSV file to my mongoDB database.

`mongoimport --db demo --collection employees --type csv --headerline --file /path/to/myfile.csv`

But I did this from mongo shell by giving a path of my local disk. Now I'm trying to implement this within my react app. Initially I proceeded with this idea - as soon as I upload an excel file, I will convert that to CSV file and I will call a post api with that CSV file in body. Upon sending that request, I will call the "mongoimport" command in my nodejs backend/server so that the data from that CSV file will be stored in my mongoDb collection. Now I can't find any solution to usmongoimport command programmatically. How can I call the "Mongoimport" command in my nodejs server code? I couldn't find any documentation regarding it.

If that is not the right way of doing this task, please suggest me any entirely other way of achieving this task.
In Layman's terms I want to import data from an excel file to MongoDb database using Reactjs/nodejs app.

Answer (score 0):

how are you?
First of all, mongoimport also allows you to import TSV files (same command as for CSV but putting --type tsv), many times friendlier to use with Excel.

Regarding mongoImport, I regret to report that mongoImport cannot be used by any means other than the command line.

What you can do from NodeJs is execute commands in the same way that they are executed by a terminal. For this you can use the [child_proccess Module](https://stackabuse.com/executing-shell-commands-with-node-js/) or [Exec Function](https://stackabuse.com/executing-shell-commands-with-node-js/#:%7E:text=The%20exec%20Function,files%20in%20our%20current%20directory.).
I hope that helps even a little.
Regards!

Comment: Thank you. But those modules might make my work complicated in the future. Can you think of any other way to add excel data to mongoDB? Open to any suggestion